# Grabbing camera image from ARCore Camera

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

Im trying to grab the camera frames from the ARCore Camera. I used the following code to do so,

```
var image = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes();
```

The above line of code works fine but the issue is that it is slow. The screen lags once I include this line in my code. Is there any other alternative way to acquire raw image from ARCore probably using `ARBackgroundRenderer`?

Comment: OpenGL ES or Vulkan?

Comment: Im using OpenGl ArCore